# Trouble enabling Azure ADDS auth for storage account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, wvd

The error is simply that the resource is not found, the resource ID it shows is the Tenant ID for Azure AD.

I am able to join VMs to Azure AD DS and mount the storage via the connect options from the portal but we are setting up FSLogix and need Azure ADDS auth for the file shares.

The Azure AD DS does exist in a classic vnet but that has not stopped other ARM resources from seeing it and using it/joining to it.

I have tried creating/joining the Storage account using PowerShell but the same error is given.

The only thing I can find (apart from the classic vnet + ADDS) is that the Azure AD Tenant is not linked to the subscription where Azure ADDS lives.

from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/390517/azure-files-linking-to-azure-ad.html): "You also have to purchase an ADDS subscription on top of the file share subscription to be able to link ad to file share."

Both ADDS and the Storage account are in the same sub.

Comment: Update: Took a look at another tenant with Azure AD DS and despite the Azure AD not being linked to the subscription Azure Files was able to be configured with adds auth. So perhaps I am back to pointing my issues at the classic vnet.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, Joining storage to Azure ADDS is not supported if AADDS is classic. Needed to upgrade it before proceeding.